# Any good plots for 2 categorical predictors and 1 continuous response?

Tags: data-visualization

Does any one know of any good plots for 2 categorical predictors with 1 continuous response?

Each categorical predictor has 2 levels each.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a small example dataset for people to work with? Are the categorical responses correlated with each other? How are you modeling them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use box plots to get an information-dense visualisation. 
I see two options to approach this:

1. Plot the continuous dependent variable over each level of each predictor (four boxes)
2. Generate an interaction term between your categorical variables, so that you get a variable with four levels, one for each combination of predictors. Plot the continuous dependent variable over the interaction term.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a bar plot like [this](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar-28.png) one? You would have two sets of bars with two different colors in each set. [Here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html) is how it is done in R's ggplot.